# no way to run commands as a login shell in terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I'm using ruby version manager [rvm](https://rvm.io/) which requires its commands to be run in a login shell.

gnome-terminal provides an option for commands to run as a login shell as described [here](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal).

however, there's not any similar option in patheon-terminal.
is there a work around for this issue?

Comment: for now I have to run `bash --login` everytime I open a terminal, which is inconvenient imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `shell` key to `bash --login` doesn't work, however I managed to fix that with the following workaround:

create a file named `bashlogin` in `/bin` directory with the following content

```
#!/bin/sh
exec bash --login
```

mark it as executable

`sudo chmod +x /bin/bashlogin`

and finally set the terminal `shell` key

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings shell 'bashlogin'`

Comment: FYI, the setting location has changed in ElementaryOS 5.0 Juno. It's now located in  `gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings shell 'bashlogin'`

Comment: the answer is updated now

Comment: It worked for me on **elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera**

Answer (score 2):

You can set the key `shell` under `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` in dconf-editor or via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings shell 'bash --login'
```

Comment: It doesn't work, terminal now hangs and shows no shell prompt.

Comment: it seems that the `shell` key doesn't accept commands with arguments.

Comment: @AboudZakaria My terminal hangs, too. How can I recover it?

Answer (score 0):

If like me you use zsh :

change

```
#!/bin/sh
exec bash --login
```

by :

```
#!/bin/zsh
exec zsh --login
```